# How to continue indexing documents in elasticsearch(rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

So I ran this command `rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='AutoPartsMapper' FORCE=true` to index documents in elasticsearch.In my database I have 10 000 000 records=)...it takes (I think) one day to index this...When indexing was running my computer turned off...(I indexed 2 000 000 documents)Is it possible to continue indexing documents?

Answer (score 1):

If you use rails 4.2+ you can use ActiveJob to schedule and leave it running. So, first generate it with this

```
bin/rails generate job elastic_search_index
```

This will give you class and method perform:

```
class ElasticSearchIndexJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform
    # impleement here indexing
    AutoPartMapper.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force:true
    AutoPartMapper.__elasticsearch__.import
  end
end
```

Set the sidekiq as your active job provider and from console initiate this with:

```
ElasticSearchIndexJob.perform_later
```

This will set the active job and execute it on next free job but it will free your console. You can leave it running and check the process in bash later:

```
ps aux | grep side
```

this will give you something like: `sidekiq 4.1.2 app[1 of 12 busy]`

Have a look at this post that explains them

http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-integrate-sidekiq-with-activejob/

Hope it helps

Comment: Note that the question is about continuing indexing from where the last run finished. A background job will still require to be run to completion in one go which may not be feasible.

Comment: Sorry about that, the question was updated later. II think that the process needs to be restarted I would definitely use sidekiq for this since it you do not have to console running while the prcoess runs with perform_later...sidekiq has logs that can be tailed and monitored for erros

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in `elasicsearch-rails` afaik but you could write a simple task to do that.

```
namespace :es do
  task :populate, [:start_id] => :environment do |_, args|
    start_id = args[:start_id].to_i

    AutoPartsMapper.where('id > ?', start_id).order(:id).find_each do |record|
      puts "Processing record ##{record.id}"
      record.__elasticsearch__.index_document
    end
  end
end
```

Start it with `bundle exec rake es:populate[<start_id>]` passing the id of the record from which to start the next batch.

Note that this is a simplistic solution which will be much slower than batch indexing.

**UPDATE**

Here is a batch indexing task. It is much faster and automatically detects the record from which to continue. It does make an assumption that previously imported records were processed in increasing id order and without gaps. I haven't tested it but most of the code is from a production system.

```
namespace :es do
  task :populate_auto => :environment do |_, args|
    start_id = get_max_indexed_id
    AutoPartsMapper.find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000).where('id > ?', start_id).order(:id) do |records|
      elasticsearch_bulk_index(records)
    end
  end

  def get_max_indexed_id
    AutoPartsMapper.search(aggs: {max_id: {max: {field: :id }}}, size: 0).response[:aggregations][:max_id][:value].to_i
  end

  def elasticsearch_bulk_index(records)
    return if records.empty?
    klass = records.first.class
    klass.__elasticsearch__.client.bulk({
      index: klass.__elasticsearch__.index_name,
      type: klass.__elasticsearch__.document_type,
      body: elasticsearch_records_to_index(records)
    })
  end

  def self.elasticsearch_records_to_index(records)
    records.map do |record|
      payload = { _id: record.id, data: record.as_indexed_json }
      { index: payload }
    end
  end
end
```